# Redirect/push user using post method in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to redirect or push user in an action to a post route with some parameters but it seems all the functions such as push and redirect work with get method. 
Is there any way to change the method to post or any work around this?

```
return Acction:push("/SOME_URL", ["PARAM"=>"param"]);
return Acction:redirect("/SOME_URL?PARAM=param");
```

Assume "param" is long enough to exceed get method limitation.